# In this for/of loop, what's the equivalent of a traditional IE11 for loop?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to make the code below compatible with IE11, but I'm stuck at the for/of loop line (line 10).

```
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
const targetNode = document.getElementById('some-id');

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    // Use traditional 'for loops' for IE 11
    for(let mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
            console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
        }
        else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
            console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
        }
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

// Later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```

I believe mutationsList is an iterable nodeList (but I could be wrong). With respect to that, how do I translate `for(let mutation of mutationsList) {` into a traditional for loop? Could you also translate `for(let mutation of mutationsList) {` into simpler terms for me as someone who only understands basic JavaScript?

Comment: `for (let x of y)` == `for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) x = y[i]`

Comment: Use https://babeljs.io/

Answer (score 1):

Traditional for loop:

```
for(var i=0; i<mutationsList.length; i++) {
    var mutation = mutationsList[i];
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
        console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
    }
    else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
        console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
    }
}
```

for...of is a type of for statement to cycles through iterables(mutationsList[index]) until it reaches the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

This is ES6 and you want ES5:

```
 for(let mutation of mutationsList) {
```

translates

```
for(var mutation = 0; mutation < mutationsList.length; mutation++){
   var something = mutationsList[mutation] ; // access the element
}
```

Comment: Should `mutationsList++` be `mutation++`?

Answer (score 0):

[`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loops enumerate the iterator present on [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator), using the [iterable protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols). This means that the behavior of the iterator will be completely sidestepped by a traditional [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for). That said, in many cases you are dealing with an array or array-like object that can be enumerated using integer indices.

For these simple cases they translate approximately [like so](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=GYewTgFANgpgLgAgB4JMBBtAjAGgEw4DMAugJQIDeAUAggMYgB2AziLAHRQgDmESpVAL5A&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.9.0&externalPlugins=):

```js
for(let x of [1,2,3]) {
  console.log(x)
}
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```js
for (var _i = 0, _arr = [1, 2, 3]; _i < _arr.length; _i++) {
  var x = _arr[_i];
  console.log(x);
}
```

In your code, `for...of` is being used to enumerate the array of `MutationRecord` objects passed to the `MutationObserver` callback. `for...of` works on arrays, because `Array` has `Symbol.iterator` on its prototype. A plain-old for loop will also work, because arrays have elements with keys that correspond to integers, that can be accessed using the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) (eg. `arr[0]`).

Answer (score 0):

The [for...of statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) not support IE browser, so, you could use [for...in statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) or [for statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) to loop through the list, they are supporting IE browser.

Try to modify your code as below:

```
for(let mutation in mutationsList) {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
        console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
    }
    else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
        console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
    }
}
```